# OCaml Passing abstract type from one module to another

Tags: ocaml

In a module called `State`, we have an abstract type `t`. We're now trying to make an entirely separate module which contains a function that takes in a `State.t` (its type starts with `State.t -> (* stuff *)`).

However, when we try to call that function from within our `State` module, passing in an object of type `t`, we get the following error:

```
Error: This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type State.t
State.t is abstract because no corresponding cmi file was found in path.
```

We assume this is happening because the other module is expecting an abstract type, but from inside the `State` module, the abstract type is concrete. Our question is, how do we make that object abstract again so that we can pass it into the other module?

Comment: This sounds like you have a cyclic dependency problem. Could you show us a minimal example of problematic code along with how you compile it?

Comment: I tried this code https://gist.github.com/jochasinga/fc7ba6cb9128a6864282e69db7dac149 on utop and it doesn't get that error. Can you produce the problematic modules code?

Comment: Also: Did you compile State before the new module?